# Expand data section to use external memory

Tags: gcc, embedded, ld, avr

I've connected an external memory (Alliance AS6C62256, 32K * 8) to my Atmega128 through the XMEM interface because my data section is getting very big. To test the connection, I tried to write data onto the memory and it worked like a charm.

Now, I would like to know how to extend the data section to use the internal and external memory, so from address 0x0100 to 0x90FF (not 0xFFFF because I only have a 32K*8 memory). I imagine I will have to change the linker script.

Answer (score 0):

This [website](https://scienceprog.com/adding-external-memory-to-atmega128/) describes the process of compiling for a chip with external memory. You will need to add something similar to the following line to your linker options.

```
-Wl,--section-start,.data=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x8030ff
```

The exact values will depend on how much memory you are adding and how you plan on using it.

Comment: Yeah I already tried this but the data section is still not on the external memory, I don't know why.